# Shell script should wait until kubernetes pod is running

Tags: bash, shell, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

In a simple bash script I want to run multiple `kubectl` and `helm` commands, like:

```
helm install \
  cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager \
  --namespace cert-manager \
  --create-namespace \
  --version v1.5.4 \
  --set installCRDs=true
kubectl apply -f deploy/cert-manager/cluster-issuers.yaml
```

My problem here is, that after the `helm install` command I have to wait until the cert-manager pod is running, then the `kubectl apply` command can be used. Right now the script is calling it too early, so it will fail.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/65938572/4957508 help? (Answer in the Question, potentially)

Comment: I know that, @Aserre; I was pointing to the *Question*, which includes `kubectl wait --for condition=Ready ...` as a potential solution.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really mean to close this; I didn't realize it had a [tag:bash] tag -- please ping me if the answer doesn't solve your problem and I'll be happy to reopen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As stated in the comments `kubectl wait` is the way to go.
Example from the `kubectl wait --help`

```text
Examples:
  # Wait for the pod "busybox1" to contain the status condition of type "Ready"
  kubectl wait --for=condition=Ready pod/busybox1
```

This way your script will pause until specified pod is Running, and `kubectl` will output

```text
<pod-name> condition met
```

to STDOUT.

---

`kubectl wait` is still in experimental phase. If you want to avoid experimental features, you can achieve similar result with bash `while` loop.
By pod name:

```sh
while [[ $(kubectl get pods <pod-name> -o 'jsonpath={..status.conditions[?(@.type=="Ready")].status}') != "True" ]]; do
   sleep 1
done
```

or by label:

```sh
while [[ $(kubectl get pods -l <label>=<label-value> -o 'jsonpath={..status.conditions[?(@.type=="Ready")].status}') != "True" ]]; do
   sleep 1
done
```